Replace HID headlamp assembly with halogen assembly (downgrade)
I have a 2014 Hyundai Santa Fe Limited.  Both headlamps have large amounts of the chrome reflective material flaking off (see Debris in headlamp assembly, fire hazard?).  I need to replace the units as the lights are virtually useless at night.  The dealer quoted me $2500 per assembly, not including labor.  I can get them around $1100 from various sites and install them myself just fine.
I'm wondering, though, if I could just use a halogen-based assembly instead.  I'm not in love with the HIDs and would be perfectly happy with regular lights and they are considerably cheaper. But I admit I really don't know how the electrical system overall works in a car.
Simplified example: in a house, for example, I have a breaker with a certain load.  I know if I replace a standard light bulb with an LED, I will be drawing less power so all is good.  Can I use the same logic in a car?  My assumption is a HID bulb uses less power but I could be wrong.

I fully admit I have not done any research on this.  My assumption is that the power coming into the entire assembly is the same.

Here's a Hyundai link to wiring diagrams (lighting); https://portal-diagnostov.com/en/2020/03/26/headlights-hyundai-santa-fe-limited-2014-system-wiring-diagrams/

I would suggest looking for aftermarket replacements instead, you'll find plenty of products for way less than either of those prices. Or get replacements off ebay or a breaker's yard.

Any good recommendations for an aftermarket site?  There is a junk yard near me I plan on hitting up this weekend.

Thanks for the wiring diagram, will take a look.
